# The analyticity on a closed ball

Tags: cv.complex-variables

In complex analysis, how to understand statements like **a fuction $f$ is analytic on $\bar B(0,1)$** ? I cannot figure out the notion of analyticity at a boundary point. Thank you.

Comment: Typically this means the function extends to an analytic function on some (unspecified) open neighborhood of the closed ball.

Comment: In general, $f$ is analytic on a set $E$ if it is analytic on some open neighborhood of $E$.

Comment: Thank both of you. Such understanding helps a lot!